# cron expression to run a webjob at 8 am everyday in azure

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I actually require an cron expression to automatically restart an app at 8 am every day. for that I have to create an scheduled webjob in azure but i'm not getting the exact cron expression.

Comment: There is _so much_ [documentation on this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer.md), you should be able to figure this one out. *TIP* running a WebJob locally with a TimerTrigger and the cron expression you think might be OK shows you the next runtimes for the job. This helps with determining the right cron expression.

Comment: I tried using this 0 0 8 1/1 * ? cron expression on azure webjob but its notifying that it is an invalid cron expression.

Comment: The link I sent you has examples, like *To trigger once every hour from 9 AM to 5 PM*. Those are simple to understand and to adapt to your needs. BTW are you using it for a TimerTrigger or in the portal?

Comment: I'm using it in the portal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to created a scheduled WebJob which will fired at 8:00 AM.

I suggest you could try to use below cron.

```
At 8:00 AM every day: 0 0 8 * * *
```

More details about how to set the cron, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON).

Result:

[image]

Besides, if you want to make sure your web jobs will continue worked. I suggest you should enable the "Always On" setting to be enabled on the app.

About how to enable it, you could refer to below steps:

[image]

Notice: This technique is available to Web Apps running in Basic, Standard or Premium mode